# Difference between @Inject and @ValueMapValue annotations

Tags: java, model, aem, sling

While reading **AEM** documentation about using **models**, 
I couldn't figure out what is the **difference** between **@Inject** and **@ValueMapValue** annotation above the field.

I tried using both, and they both seems the same, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are not the same, `@Inject` is a general purpose annotation that makes the value available from a number of injectors.

`@ValueMapValue` is an injector specific annotation that will specifically pick value from valuemap injector. It is equivalent to `@Inject @Source("valuemap")`

When the injected value is available only from one injector, their behavior would be the same, however if the same property is provided by two different injectors (say script-binding and valuemap) they might inject different values. Read more [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html).